# Slick Grid Allow Clicks to go through to Formatter objects

Tags: slickgrid

I have something called a panel formatter i made which just places some inline configurable html elements in the cell.

However, currently the click into one the elements is being blocked by slick grid's code. I've tried this approach:

```
gridObj.onClick.subscribe(function(e,args) {
    var target = $(e.target);

    if (target.hasClass("panelFormatter")) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

However, this does not allow the events to file through to this panel object. Is there a way to make the clicks (and hover for that matter). Flow through to the formatters html objects?

Or is the only way moving this object outside of the grid and positioning it absolutely?

-Tim

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you want to stop `click` and `hover` events on `panelFormatter` cells or do you want to listen to them and do something?

Comment: I want the click and hover to go through the panel formatter and act on them rather than the grid row.